# Can you not use T as a global variable

Tags: java, generics

I have the following:

```
public class foo {
public static Request<T> request;

public void doSomething()
{
 request = getRequest();
}
}
```

but the compiler says that it `cannot Resolve Symbol T`

however this works: (ie T is defines and it builds.)

```
public class foo{   

 public void doSomething()
 {
  Request<T> request = getRequest();
 }
}
```

am i missing something simple here?

Request is a public class that exists in the solution. It is a Google volley class for interest sake.

`getRequest()` is a function that returns a `Request<T>`

Real code:

```
 public class Network {
 //Used to get Last Request
 public static Request<T> previousRequest;

 ...

 public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, 1, 2));
    try {
        req.getHeaders().put("Authorization", "Bearer " + getToken());
    } catch (AuthFailureError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, PrintRequest(req));
    previousRequest = req;     <<<<<<<<<<<<******* incomparable Types error
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

...
```

}

Comment: No, that definitely does not work.

Comment: `public class [...]`, `getRequest()`? Exact error? `T` is undefined in both cases.

Comment: its psudocode, the actual code is much more complex, hence the reason I chose to isolate my issue. and remove all the irrelevant stuff.

Comment: You must have removed too much, because your second snippet has the same problem as your first. `T` is not defined anywhere _shown_.

Comment: What do you mean by that? T is stands for A Generic Type not?

Comment: We cannot give you a sensible answer here.  If you're confused about why a certain construct _does_ work, when another one doesn't, you'll need to post code that actually does work.

Comment: `T` is an identifier, just like any variable name.  There is no magical special meaning to the identifier `T`.

Comment: Again, there is no way the code with the `previousRequest` `static` field compiles. Not the method, the actual field declaration. That will not compile, assuming `T` is meant to be a generic type.

Comment: Yes, That is my exact issue

Comment: So how do i store a variable of type Request <T> ?

Comment: Well, `T` is not defined.

Comment: What you're trying to do may not be doable in Java.  If you have a non-generic `Network` and you want to be able to call its `addToRequestQueue` with a `Request<String>` one time, a `Request<SomeOtherClass>` the second time, and so on with different classes, you can't store the request in `previousRequest` and have it keep track of what generic type you were using in the request.  Java doesn't keep that info ("type erasure").

Comment: I don't know what the solution is, and it may depend on the rest of your code.  You might need `public static Request<?> previousRequest`, but I have trouble remembering all the rules about wildcards, so this could be wrong or could make other things notwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addToRequest` *will* compile, because you're defining a generic method.  The syntax of the method definition (putting `<T>` before the result type) is what tells the compiler you're defining a generic method.  This syntax *defines* `T`, so that you can use it in the rest of the method.  Similarly, `public class SomeClass<T>` *defines* `T`, so you can use it in the rest of the class.  But other syntaxes do not define the generic parameter, including this one:

```
public static Request<T> previousRequest;
```

This is not the definition of a generic variable (there is no such thing), and thus it does not define `T`.  Therefore, `T` has to be defined somewhere else.  And in your example, it isn't.  (The `T` that's defined for the generic method `addToRequestQueue` is defined only for that method, and `previousRequest` is declared outside the method.)

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense now. Many thanks for the explanation, I was not aware of the fact that when defining a generic method it actually defined T. I was under the impression that T just meant anything.